# How to remove empty rows from Splunk table?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-formula

In my query response, few time I don't get data and it's just adding row empty row.
I like to remove empty row it's my regex not found any records.

```
index=stg host="stg-host1" " Number of data processed for day is"
| rex "(?<Records>[^\s]+) from file"
| timechart max(Records) as TotalRecords 
span=45min
```

Expected: Remove all empty rows. Row should only available if TotalRecords has some value.

Current Table:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to remove results that contain a specific field with a null value, in this case `TotalRecords`:

```
| where isnotnull(TotalRecords)
```

Comment: This also working  ```index=stg host="stg-host1" " Number of data processed for day is"
| rex "(?<Records>[^\s]+) from file"
| timechart max(Records) as TotalRecords 
span=45min | where isnotnull(TotalRecords)```

Comment: I tried ```index=stg host="stg-host1" " Number of data processed for day is" | rex "(?<Records>[^\s]+) from file" | timechart max(Records) as TotalRecords  span=45min cont=false``` , it's works.

Comment: Yeah, `cont=f` will work under some circumstances because it stops Splunk from *padding* out the timechart with null values to make it a continuous series but `| where isnotnull(x)` will always work.

Comment: thanks you once again..